# Unable to get audio output from paired Bluetooth device

Tags: sound, bluetooth

Hy frnds, I am using byte DM5710BT Bluetooth headset which is working very fine in windows 7 . But in Ubuntu12.10 I had paired it, and made sure it is connected. But still I am not getting audio from my device instead In-built speaker of laptop is giving audio. Could anyone please help me with how to use Bluetooth headset in ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: paste the relevant output of `lspci -vnn` from the  or output of dmesg when you pair your device

Comment: here is the link details of terminal output that I get:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/268442/unable-to-connect-bluetooth-headset

Comment: Is your headset listed as an audio output device from *"Sound Settings"*?

Answer (score 1):

Edit /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf and under [General], add the line Enable=Source. Restart Blueooth. It's worked for me. (Ubuntu 13.04)

Comment: worked on 16.04

Answer (score 0):

First, login as root and run `bluetoothctl` along with the following commands:

```
nirvan@nirvan:~$ sudo -i
root@nirvan:~# bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# power off
[bluetooth]# power on
[bluetooth]# scan on
```